# Listbox add items from database and sort + delete duplicates

Tags: database, delphi, ms-access, listbox, delphi-xe3

I'd need some help since I don't see any solution after doing some search...

I have a database Database.mdb, which have a few tables, I'm reading specific table Fixtures, which have fields ID, ChNo, Default and Manufacturer;

I then have a form on which I'd like a user to be able to choose from each fixture, but would like to sort it by manufacturer firstly.
So, I added ListBox component on a form, and started to populate it using the code provided:

```
    procedure TPatchNew1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var No, No2: integer;
begin
No2:=0;
AdoQuerySearchFixtures.SQL.Text:='SELECT Manufacturer FROM Fixtures';
AdoQuerySearchFixtures.Open;
ManuNo:=AdoQuerySearchFixtures.RecordCount;
While No2 < No do
  begin
  ManufacturerListbox.Items.Add;
  AdoQuerySearchFixtures.Close;
  AdoQuerySearchFixtures.SQL.Clear;
  AdoQuerySearchFixtures.SQL.Text:='SELECT Manufacturer FROM Fixtures WHERE ID='+IntToStr(No2+1);
  AdoQuerySearchFixtures.Open;
  ManufacturerListbox.Items[No2].Caption:=AdoQuerySearchFixtures.Fields[0].AsString;
  No2:=No2+1;
  end;

end;
```

This does the trick, but I'd like it to first: merge all duplicates, so that the fixtures with the same Manufacturer field value are all shown only after the Listbox item is clicked (I believe I'll be able to do that changing SQL text to "WHERE Manufacturer=something"), but there are not 100 items in listbox, if I have 90 fixtures from same manufacturer;
At last, before the listbox is populated, I'd like it to be sorted alphabetically, from A to Z.
Should I firstly read all manufacturers to sort of a record or array, then find duplicates and delete them, and later sort it, lastly filling in to listbox items, or is there any other way?
It that's the way, how to do it? I give up after this whole day.. :(

Thanks.

Cheers

Comment: Open a query to count the records and then query for each item separately? Sorting and grouping can easily be done by the database query itself. So start to work on a database tutorial first

Comment: You don't have any specific problem, you are asking for advice instead, so i think it is bad question for SO. As Rufo mentioned, you can do it with SQL (but you need to learn at least basics of SQL) or preload all data and do what you want in memory (for example in array).

Comment: Sorry for being late, been off for holidays... [Merry Christmas to all bdw].
Um, I did check a lot about database queries, however never gotten that far to see anything like sorting in the query itself. But won't that make the query quite busy and slow? I mean, I'm going to have one database with several tables, from which I'm basically reading and writing all the time. One table is writing entries every 0,5 seconds, 2 tables are read every 0,5 seconds, for all row values, so I wanted to hang the sorting and other job to the program itself... Is this not a good idea?

Comment: @AndreiGalatyn, I'm sorry if I came for an advice...
But, from my perspective, I don't even know how to do that, not that I just don't know how to do it the best way... So that's why I think it is a question.. :/
I must say, that at the same time that I'm thankful for all help and knowledge learned from SO, I'm kinda disappointed how you guys sometimes act so harsh to the basics asked. Afterall, it is a forum, and it is opened, so that people can ask questions, and none of them is addressed to any of you experts. It's a choice to help and answer - and you always do, but also criticize a lot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to display in a listbox the names of manufacturers who supply fixtures. It's not clear from your question, but I am assuming that you have at least two tables: one of manufacturers and one of fixtures. The manufacturer will be a foreign key in the fixtures table.

If you want to load the listbox with the manufacturers, then it is better to take the data from the manufacturers table as you are (almost) guaranteed to have no duplicates there. Your sql query would be

```
select id, name 
from manufacturers
order by name
```

If you want only manufacturers who appear in the fixtures table, then alter the query thus

```
select id, name
from manufacturers
where exists (select 1 from fixtures
where fixtures.manufacturer = manufacturers.id)
order by name
```

Load the listbox in the following manner

```
manulist.items.clear;
with qManufacturers do
 begin
  open;
  while not eof do
   begin
    manulist.items.addobject (fieldbyname ('name').asstring,
                              tobject (fieldbyname ('id').asinteger));
    next
   end;
  close
 end;
```

Then when a name is chosen from the listbox, you can display the fixtures thus

```
with manulist do
 begin
  manu:= longint (Items.Objects[itemindex]);  // manufacturer key
  mname:= items[itemindex];                   // manufacturer name
 end;
```

with qFixtures do
    begin
     params[0].asinteger:= manu;
     open;
     ....
    end;

qFixtures would be something like

```
select id, name, ...
from fixtures
where manufacturer = :p1
```

Comment: I applaude your effort to help the guy No'am, but I'm afraid it's clear from his SQL statements that he doesn't have two separate tables for Manufacturers and Fixtures. I agree some database normalisation would probably benefit his situation. [+1]

Comment: Sorry for being late to you too. Anyway, as Sam already mentioned - it's not true that it's not clear from my question if I have one or two tables: I wrote that I have a database, which has a few tables, but I'm reading *one specific - Fixtures*, which *has fields ID, ChNo, Default and Manufacturer*. So, it's all in one table. Every fixture (only identified by ID so far, because the name isn't important for a question) has a Manufacturer, which is not unique.
However, I also applause your effort to help me, and I think that I got a few ideas out of your examples anyway, so I'm going to try

Comment: them out and see if I succeed to make the correct SQL statement I need for it...
However, you also gave me some idea to expand the database with separate table for manufacturers, so that every fixture in fixtures table has a manufacturer id in a table, and other table has all of the manufacturers listed, so that there are no duplicates, and therefore I load in the table Manufacturers, and from there on I search for fixtures based on selected manufacturer in the listbox. Don't know how I didn't came up with this idea earlier... @Sam, is this what you meant to do the "database normalisation"?

Comment: Good. Used Manufacturer separate table instead, and loaded it into listbox with:
SELECT Brand FROM Manufacturer order by Brand;
and while not eof do begin ManufacturerListbox.Items.Add.Caption:=fieldbyname('Brand').AsString; next;
That works flawlessly. I hope that I'll get along the fixture show now just fine. I was missing just a part of these queries and some open mind I guess... thanks! :)

Comment: @StillBeginnerMarc you're doing fine. keep going.